# Checkbox com dados do Firebase no Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firestore

Eu criei um método que retorna os dados do Firebase e cria uma lista de verificação contendo o nome.

O problema é que, quando seleciono uma caixa de seleção, ela seleciona todas. O que fiz foi extrair o Firebase (do mesmo documento que retorna o nome), um "isSelected" como um bool. Em seguida, ele puxa o valor do documento e, quando seleciona a caixa de seleção, entra no documento do usuário selecionado e atualiza o valor no Firebase.

Como resolver isso sem precisar usar o bool da caixa de seleção no Firebase?

Outra coisa, quando você adiciona o "post", quero que você pegue o UID dos usuários selecionados e crie um documento no Firebase com um array contendo os uid dos usuários selecionados. Como vou obter o UID do usuário selecionado?

Tipo, eu sei como adicionar no Firebase os dados e etc, mas eu não sei como faço para pegar os UID's somente dos usuários selecionados e criar um array contendo ele...

Resumindo: Quero criar uma lista de checkbox com os nomes dos usuários (isso já tá fazendo no código abaixo), com um value do checkbox para cada um (selecionado ou não selecionado - pois se declarar a variável e utilizar a mesma, quando seleciona um usuário seleciona todas as caixas de todos os itens).

E quero que quando insere no Firebase, ele pega o UID dos usuários selecionados (apenas os selecionados) e cria um campo no documento chamado "uids" contendo o UID dos usuários.

Aqui o código que criei para criar o checkbox com os dados do Firebase:

```
Widget _sendFor() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Send for',
          style: kLabelStyle,
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
          child: new StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(_idUsuarioLogado)
                .collection("friends")
                .snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
              return new ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {
                  //Dgir130wejV0zDERzUgNqr1ItFN2
                  return new CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      document["name"],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    value: _valueCheckbox,
                    onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                      Map<String, dynamic> dadosUpdate = {
                        "isSelected": _valueCheckbox,
                      };
                      setState(() {
                        Firestore.instance
                            .collection('users')
                            .document(document["uid"])
                            .updateData(dadosUpdate);
                        _valueCheckbox = newValue;
                        print(newValue);
                      });
                    },
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa, tenta elaborar melhor ela por favor! Pelo que entendi, você quer criar uma lista com o nome dos usuários retornados do firebase e depois na hora que salvar, criar um documento só com o código daqueles usuários que selecionou? É isso mesmo? **Edite** a sua pergunta ai pra deixar mais claro.

Comment: Quero criar uma lista de checkbox contendo o nome retornando do Firebase. Eu já fiz isso, mas o problema é que quando seleciono uma caixa do checkbox todos ps itens são selecionados.
Também gostaria de criar um array com os UIDs dos usuários selecionados para add no Firebase, mas como faço isso?
Eu editei o post

Comment: Entendi seu ponto agora, assim que eu tiver um tempo livre, construo uma resposta pro seu problema!

Comment: Sem problemas, amigo.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criei um exemplo rápido no [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) para você entender como deverá funcionar o seu esquema, caso não consiga entender, depois implemento melhor minha resposta com base no exemplo dado na sua pergunta (O que tu tentou até agora).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

/* Classe para fazer o controle de cada registro chego do firebase */
class Item{
  Item({this.nome, this.checked = false});
  String nome;
  bool checked;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  /* Uma lista que você irá implementar com os dados dos nomes vindo do firebase 
    Alimente ela dentro do seu StreamBuilder
  */
  final List<Item> itens = [
    Item(nome: "Matheus"), 
    Item(nome: "Júlio"), 
    Item(nome: "Caio")];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itens.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index){
            return ItemLista(item: itens[index]);
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.save),
          onPressed: salvar,
        )
      ),
    );
  }

  /* Aqui é como você vai pegar os registros selecionados apenas */
  void salvar(){
    List<Item> itensMarcados = List.from(itens.where((item) => item.checked));

    itensMarcados.forEach((item){
      print(item.nome);
    });
  }
}


/* Criei aqui um widget que irá controlar o próprio estado */

class ItemLista extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemLista({ Key key, this.item }) : super(key: key);

  final Item item;

  @override
  _ItemListaState createState() => _ItemListaState();
}

class _ItemListaState extends State<ItemLista> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text(widget.item.nome),
      value: widget.item.checked,
      onChanged: (bool value){
        setState((){
          widget.item.checked = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Vou tentar aqui amigo, muito obrigado!

Comment: Matheus, fiquei até agora e n consegui não kkkk
Se puder me ajudar, ficarei grato

Comment: Amigo, parece que deu certo, puxei os dados e dou print com o nome, checked e o uid ele mostra no debug. Vou tentar fazer a inserção agora.
Olha como tá o código, é assim msm? https://pastebin.com/c18iMaSA

Comment: Isso mesmo cara, dessa forma fica organizado e funcional! Basta agora só você aplicar o seu esquema de salvar os dados, entendeu certinho.

Comment: Deu certo para salvar os dados no Firebase.
Olha o que eu fiz, criei outra lista que recebe os uid apenas dos usuários selecionados e coloquei isso dentro do forEach, dps passo essa lista no mapa que adiciona no Firebase
https://pastebin.com/EEw5yz3A

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!